# Angular 2+ nested form pattern causing 'change after check' errors

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm following this [nested form pattern](http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/) by Matt Brophy. Essentially child form components create their own `FormGroup`, and append that to a `FormArray` that is passed in from the parent form component.

A problem I have run into, that Matt possibly overlooked, is that if the child `FormGroup` happens to be invalid, a 'change after check' error is thrown.

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.
```

The code for the ChildFormComponent that reproduces the problem looks like this:

```
export class ChildFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input('children')
    public children: FormArray;

    @Input('child')
    public child: ChildData;

    public childForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Initializing child form', this.child);
        this.childForm = this.toFormGroup(this.child);
        this.children.push(this.childForm);
    }

    private toFormGroup(data: ChildData) {
        const formGroup = this.fb.group({
            id: [ data.id ],
            childField1: [ data.childField1 || '', Validators.required ],
            childField2: [ '', Validators.required ],
            childHiddenField1: [ data.childHiddenField1 ]
        });

        return formGroup;
    }

}
```

You can see the difference between childField1 and childField2, where childField1 can get a valid value, whereas childField2 gets and empty string, which makes the form (and it's parent form) invalid.

The tough spot is that the `ChildData` and the `children` `FormArray` can't be available until `OnInit`.

I've tried to hack it by using a few other lifecycle hooks, but I still get the same error, so I don't know where I can safely append the child `FormGroup`.

I've [forked the repo](https://github.com/BBaysinger/ng-playground) and updated the packages, since I couldn't get [Matt's version](https://github.com/brophdawg11/ng-playground) to compile. Here is a [live demo](https://brophdawg11.github.io/ng-playground/nested-form) of how it should work.

This pattern is beautiful, and my project is already invested in it, since I didn't find this issue until I started adding validators. Is there a way to accomplish this without issues?

[Edit]: I was able to isolate the issue in a [test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310117/change-after-check-error-when-a-projected-component-sets-a-value-in-an-ancesto), and solved it from there. So marking this question as a duplicate of that.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question ... but have you seen this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8 It covers using nested forms.

Comment: There are hints of what I need to do at the very end of that video, but she goes to fast during that part, and doesn't explain well. I tried to find the code she said she would tweet, but I couldn't. :(

Comment: I found the slides, but not the code. You could try tweeting her.

Comment: I tried tweeting her. Haven't heard back yet.