# 'Change after check' error when a projected component sets a value in an ancestor

Tags: angular

I'm getting a 'change after check' error when a projected component sets a value in an ancestor component. Here is a reproduction of my issue: [plnkr.co/edit/jJNFsJdf1KDSF3Fqhfb8](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJNFsJdf1KDSF3Fqhfb8)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
    <test-component>
      <ng-template #tpl>
        <projected-component [rootComponent]="this"></projected-component>
      </ng-template>
    </test-component>
    {{change}}
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  change = 0;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  template: `
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="tplRef"></ng-template>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
  @ContentChild('tpl') tplRef: TemplateRef<any>;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'projected-component',
  template: ` 
    <div>{{parent}}</div>
  `
})
export class ProjectedComponent {
  @Input() rootComponent: TestApp;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rootComponent.change++;
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 0'. Current value: 'null: 1'.
```

I first came upon this problem from a [nested form pattern](http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/) by Matt Brophy. It's a beautiful pattern, but I think he may have overlooked this issue, or it wasn't an issue in earlier versions of Angular. My original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287972/angular-2-nested-form-pattern-causing-change-after-check-errors). I didn't have success with help on a solution, since I didn't have a simplified, live reproduction.

How can I set this up without getting errors?

Comment: How about using Output in child component and catch that in root?

Comment: Doesn't work: https://plnkr.co/edit/U8VU544s4f7QuLN15NN5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing data from the parent in the same change detection cycle. You can stop that error from being throw by simply wrapping your change in a `setTimeout()` call to ensure that it runs after the change detection cycle completes.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.rootComponent);
    setTimeout(() => this.rootComponent.change++);
}
```

You typically won't run into these issues tho because it typically is some user event that triggers a change in data, not some methods running during the change detection lifecycle (well at least not change parent data).

That being said, it typically isn't best to be modifying data that is owned by another component though. As @Harry Ninh mentioned, it would be best to broadcast out an event to notify the parent that the data needs to be updated (in this case you would still need to wrap with the `setTimeout()` since you would still be broadcasting that event to change data in the parent in the same change detection cycle).

Comment: Oh jeeze. I'm pretty sure I tried the setTimeout thing at some point. It certainly works in the plunk...